# Heuristic for "this" and closures OK? (Expression trees)

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees

Consider the following Expression:

```
class A {
    int x;
    public void Method(int y) {
        Expression<Func<bool>> expr=() => x == y;
        //...
```

Here, the expression involves an automatically created closure for `y`, and a reference to `this` of type `A` for the (implicit) `this.x`.  Both will be represented as a `MemberExpression` on a `ConstantExpression` in the expression tree.  Given an expression such as `expr` or a more complicated expression with a this reference and/or a closure, **I want identify that a particular `ConstantExpression` is actually "this" or an implicitly constructed closure** to be able to regenerate C# from an expression tree ([ExpressionToCode](http://code.google.com/p/expressiontocode/)).

I built a "solution" using some heuristics since there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution.

- Closures and `this` in lambda's are always in `ConstantExpressions`.
- Closures and `this` are never `null`.
- Both are classes, not value types - you cannot capture a reference to `this` from a struct.  That's quite fortunate, because telling `default(StructType).Method()` from `this.Method()` would otherwise be impossible whenever `this == default(StructType)`.
- Builtin types (string, Enums, decimal, Type, all primitives) are actually real constants, not `this` or a closure
- Closures and Anonymous types start with `<` and are annotated with `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`

  - Closure names contain the string `DisplayClass`, anonymous types contain `AnonymousType`
  - Anonymous types are generic, closures are not.
  - Closures are nested classes, anonymous types are not.
- `this` must be a normal type: not `CompilerGenerated` and does not start with `<`

Are the above heuristics sufficient to distinguish between real constants, `this`, closures and anonymous types? I.e. are there cases where these heuristics fail, or am I missing any?  Is this likely to break in future .NET versions?

***Edit:*** I first asked this question in an open-ended fashion, without result; I rewrote the question to include what I've come up so far.  Any suggestions much appreciated - the bounty's expiring tomorrow, any idea at all is welcome...

Comment: Are you sure your assumption is correct? In my opinion (i'm not an expert ;)), the x in the expression could just be a 'reference' to a int without any knowledge of the A (and no way to find about an A from the expression)

Comment: ok i'm wrong it's possible with expression trees (and it's obvious ^^)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to get close to an answer.  I'm not sure it's possible - I've added my current thoughts on the matter, which are that you'll need to detect and differentiate between compiler generated types, real constants, and user types - and note that the compiler also generates anonymous types that aren't for closures.

Comment: Anonymous types use properties, closures use fields: that might be a path to differentiate those two, anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I manage to find about the A Type from the expression:

```
class Program
{
    class A
    {
        int x;
        public Expression<Func<bool>> Method(int y)
        {
            Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => x == y;
            return expr;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expr = new A().Method(10);

        dynamic body = expr.Body;

        A instance = body.Left.Expression.Value;

        Console.Write(instance.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
```

The dynamic is just to go fast.

edit 2: got it

Comment: What you're doing here works in *this precise example* - but it won't work in general.  I bolded the relevant part of the question concerning the fact that it's an *arbitrary* expression, and added a clarifying bit as to the why's and how's that this might be achieved - thanks for looking!

Comment: i'm afraid what you want to do is impossible, from the expression point of view, there's no difference between an 'implicit' closure and a 'explicit' one...

Comment: What do you mean - explicit closure?  Closures are always implicit; and AFAIK they generate classes with `DisplayClass` in the name - at least that's part of the heuristic I'm using so far.

Comment: I was thinking closures with 'this' in opposition with closures with any other local object.

Comment: Ah, well, closures are actually implemented as independent objects to `this`.  So local variables and the like get hoisted to closure objects, but class variables are simply referenced using `this` - it's not that `this` is a field or property of the closure, but simply an independent object in a `ConstantExpression`.  That's also why closures are nested, probably: they need to be able to access private members of the surrounding class.

Comment: Guillaume, Thanks for thinking 'bout this and sharing thoughts with me - even if I haven't found a perfect solution: bounty awarded!

Comment: Thank you! No problem, it's an interesting problem, and i was a bit curious about what you tried to achieve using that ;)